# live search input

Tags: ajax, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, livesearch

I'm creating a live search input in ionic 3 
inside a form group

inside my ts file, I'm using

```
 getsubelements(selectedValue) {
        if(selectedValue){
            this.VisitesProvider.getEcolesLive(selectedValue).then((result) =>{
                this.responseData = result;

            });
        }

    }
```

and my provider look like :

```
getEcolesLive(query){
        var data = {
            "q"  :query

        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            let headers = new HttpHeaders();
            this.http.post(ecoleliveurl, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers}).
            subscribe(res =>{
                resolve(res);
                console.log(res);
            }, (err) =>{
                reject(err);
            });

        });

    }
```

I'm getting the expected result in json format from mu api server:

```
[{"name":"Ecole EC","id":"22"}]
```

I want to populate the names in a dropdown list and on click on the desired one of should replace the search input.

Comment: Does your response array contain multiple objects like this?
{"name":"Ecole EC","id":"22"}

Comment: Yes it shoud but as i only have one recorde containing the EC letters its the only one returned in fact each time a type a letter or delete the provider make a query to the rest api which respond with any name containing that or those letters , my issue is how to make that response available for my html file and build a drop down list form it the drop down should have multipole values depending on the database content

Comment: What you are after is “autocomplete” i guess. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dropdown menu in the component template like this.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
    <option [value]="i" *ngFor="let i of responseData">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In your component.

```
 onChange(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = newValue;
 }
```

Comment: Hello Anuardha , thanks for you replays it's not quet waht i exaclty want but heer is an example in the link , 
https://embed.plnkr.co/6kKpqmbow3XvDBdC5ENo/

as you can see in the above eample  i want the same bevaviour but instad of having an array data i have a ajax call made eache time o type a letter and the list should be updated each time. and on lick chnage the input. and as i said im using formGroup and formControlName instead of ngmodel so when using ngmodel it generate errors

Answer (score 0):

this is the html

```
    <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Ecole</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Search"  formControlName="ecole" (ionChange)="getsubelements($event._value)" ng-focus="focus=true"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
      <div id="search-results" ng-show="focus">
        <div class="search-result" *ngFor="let i of responseData" (click)="onChange(i.name)">{{i.name}}</div>
      </div>
```

this is the js part

the form groupe :

```
      visitData = {"name":"", "startdate":"","linkedto":"","ecole":"","selectedItem":""};
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private formBuilder: FormBuilder,public VisitesProvider:VisitesProvider) {
        this.visiteFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required],
            startdate: ['', Validators.required],
            ecole:['', Validators.required],
        });
  }
```

the two functions :

```
 getsubelements(selectedValue) {
        if(selectedValue){
            this.VisitesProvider.getEcolesLive(selectedValue).then((result) =>{
                this.responseData = result;
                var x = document.getElementById("search-results");
                x.style.display="block"
            });
        }

    }
    onChange(newValue) {
        console.log("called")
        console.log(newValue.name)
        this.visiteFormGroup.controls["ecole"].setValue(newValue);
        var x = document.getElementById("search-results");
        x.style.display="none"

    }
```

and the provider function

```
  getEcolesLive(query){
    var data = {
        "q"  :query

    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        this.http.post(ecoleliveurl, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers}).
        subscribe(res =>{
            resolve(res);
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) =>{
            reject(err);
        });

    });

}
```

i hope it will help somone :)